# javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException when using hadoop MiniDFSCluster

Tags: java, junit, hadoop, hdfs

I am using MiniDFSCluster to do junit tests.
Now I just start and close the cluster, the junit runs green. 
But I get this exception:

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=MetricsSystem,sub=Control
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.addReference(MXBeanLookup.java:120)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.register(MXBeanSupport.java:143)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.preRegister2(MBeanSupport.java:183)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:941)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.register(MBeans.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.initSystemMBean(MetricsSystemImpl.java:500)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:140)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.init(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1483)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1459)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.startDataNodes(MiniDFSCluster.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:280)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:124)
at com.myCompany.TestAll.testInit(TestAll.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about this exception?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Anyone please give me some suggestion? Or ever encountered this exception with some other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that hadoop is registering a [jmx bean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) for monitoring.  The first time hadoop starts, it registers the bean, but the second time hadoop starts, a bean with that name is already registered, resulting in the error above.

Either you are not shutting down MiniDFSCluster properly, or you are starting it more than once, or there is a bug in MiniDFSCluster that causes it to not clean up properly.

Are you calling `cluster.shutdown()` in a teardown method, as demonstrated [here](http://bigdata.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/beginners-view-of-hadoop-minidfscluster/#more-39).

Comment: I am calling cluster.shutdown() everytime. Thank you for reminding, I will check again.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do call shutdown, you're still going to get the error until 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4709 is resolved